# Selenium Server Setup Errors

Tags: selenium, command-prompt, selenium-grid

I am trying to start a Selenium server in the command line, but it returns the following message:

```
    Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\a607270>java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar -role hub
09:49:50.198 INFO - Selenium build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown'
09:49:50.199 INFO - Launching Selenium Grid hub
2017-05-30 09:49:52.134:INFO::main: Logging initialized @2625ms to org.seleniumh
q.jetty9.util.log.StdErrLog
09:49:52.167 INFO - Will listen on 4444
2017-05-30 09:49:52.276:INFO:osjs.Server:main: jetty-9.4.3.v20170317
2017-05-30 09:49:52.313:INFO:osjs.session:main: DefaultSessionIdManager workerNa
me=node0
2017-05-30 09:49:52.313:INFO:osjs.session:main: No SessionScavenger set, using d
efaults
2017-05-30 09:49:52.320:INFO:osjs.session:main: Scavenging every 660000ms
2017-05-30 09:49:52.364:INFO:osjsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.s.j.s.ServletC
ontextHandler@5e955596{/,null,AVAILABLE}
Usage: <main class> [options]
  Options:
    --version, -version
       Displays the version and exits.
       Default: false
    -browserTimeout
       <Integer> in seconds : number of seconds a browser session is allowed to
       hang while a WebDriver command is running (example: driver.get(url)). If
the
       timeout is reached while a WebDriver command is still processing, the ses
sion
       will quit. Minimum value is 60. An unspecified, zero, or negative value m
eans
       wait indefinitely.
       Default: 0
    -matcher, -capabilityMatcher
       <String> class name : a class implementing the CapabilityMatcher
       interface. Specifies the logic the hub will follow to define whether a re
quest can
       be assigned to a node. For example, if you want to have the matching proc
ess
       use regular expressions instead of exact match when specifying browser
       version. ALL nodes of a grid ecosystem would then use the same capability
Matcher,
       as defined here.
       Default: org.openqa.grid.internal.utils.DefaultCapabilityMatcher@3439f68d

    -cleanUpCycle
       <Integer> in ms : specifies how often the hub will poll running proxies
       for timed-out (i.e. hung) threads. Must also specify "timeout" option
       Default: 5000
    -custom
       <String> : comma separated key=value pairs for custom grid extensions.
       NOT RECOMMENDED -- may be deprecated in a future revision. Example: -cust
om
       myParamA=Value1,myParamB=Value2
       Default: {}
    -debug
       <Boolean> : enables LogLevel.FINE.
       Default: false
    -host
       <String> IP or hostname : usually determined automatically. Most commonly

       useful in exotic network configurations (e.g. network with VPN)
       Default: 10.56.130.102
    -hubConfig
       <String> filename: a JSON file (following grid2 format), which defines
       the hub properties
    -jettyThreads, -jettyMaxThreads
       <Integer> : max number of threads for Jetty. An unspecified, zero, or
       negative value means the Jetty default value (200) will be used.
    -log
       <String> filename : the filename to use for logging. If omitted, will log

       to STDOUT
    -maxSession
       <Integer> max number of tests that can run at the same time on the node,
       irrespective of the browser used
    -newSessionWaitTimeout
       <Integer> in ms : The time after which a new test waiting for a node to
       become available will time out. When that happens, the test will throw an

       exception before attempting to start a browser. An unspecified, zero, or
negative
       value means wait indefinitely.
       Default: -1
    -port
       <Integer> : the port number the server will use.
       Default: 4444
    -prioritizer
       <String> class name : a class implementing the Prioritizer interface.
       Specify a custom Prioritizer if you want to sort the order in which new s
ession
       requests are processed when there is a queue. Default to null ( no priori
ty = FIFO
       )
    -role
       <String> options are [hub], [node], or [standalone].
       Default: hub
    -servlet, -servlets
       <String> : list of extra servlets the grid (hub or node) will make
       available. Specify multiple on the command line: -servlet tld.company.Ser
vletA
       -servlet tld.company.ServletB. The servlet must exist in the path:
       /grid/admin/ServletA /grid/admin/ServletB
       Default: []
    -timeout, -sessionTimeout
       <Integer> in seconds : Specifies the timeout before the server
       automatically kills a session that hasn't had any activity in the last X
seconds. The
       test slot will then be released for another test to use. This is typicall
y
       used to take care of client crashes. For grid hub/node roles, cleanUpCycl
e
       must also be set.
       Default: 1800
    -throwOnCapabilityNotPresent
       <Boolean> true or false : If true, the hub will reject all test requests
       if no compatible proxy is currently registered. If set to false, the requ
est
       will queue until a node supporting the capability is registered with the
grid.
       Default: true
    -withoutServlet, -withoutServlets
       <String> : list of default (hub or node) servlets to disable. Advanced
       use cases only. Not all default servlets can be disabled. Specify multipl
e on
       the command line: -withoutServlet tld.company.ServletA -withoutServlet
       tld.company.ServletB
       Default: []

java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(Unknown Source)
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.ServerConnector.open(ServerConnector.jav
a:298)
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(Abstrac
tNetworkConnector.java:80)
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.
java:236)
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(Abstract
LifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:431)
        at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(Abstract
LifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.openqa.grid.web.Hub.start(Hub.java:184)
        at org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncherV3$2.launch(GridLauncherV3.java:
259)
        at org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncherV3.main(GridLauncherV3.java:99)
```

Can anyone help me resolve this issue? If more information is needed, I can provide it.

I am using Windows 7 Professional, and am working in a corporate setting, so there may be proxy issues.

Comment: I don't see any issue here. What you are seeing are the `INFO` logs which you haven't suppressed. Don't you see `INFO - Selenium Grid hub is up and running` at the end? Thanks

Comment: No, it just jumps straight to:
    Usage: <main class> [options], and then a very long list of options

Comment: Can you consider showing us the full stack trace? Thanks

Comment: I've included the full output by the console

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

It's quite clear from the error logs `java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind` that the default port `4444` on which **`Selenium Grid Hub`** listens is in use by some other application. So you can consider using some other port for **`Selenium Grid Hub`** as follows:

```
C:\Users>java -jar C:\Utility\selenium-server-standalone\selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar -role hub -port 5786
```

You can access the Selenium Grid Server console through **http://localhost:5786/grid/console**

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: @Jay Glad to be able to help you :) Upvote the Answer if it was useful to you. Thanks