# while doing selenium testing-- I am getting an error

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

```
[0.228][SEVERE]: bind() returned an error, errno=98: Address already in use (98)
Nov 20, 2017 1:03:49 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
```

Comment: As you are seeing `bind() returned an error` it is a possible duplicate of [Selenium Server Setup Errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44262919/selenium-server-setup-errors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you  try to run multiple services on same port number, you will get binding error . From your logs, it is evident that A service is already running on the specific **port number** on which you fired up selenium server . Change the port number.

```
--httpPort=9000
```

Answer (score -1):

Download the latest version of chrome driver and set the property .
You can download from here https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/